# How to find the total device storage capacity in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Trying to fetch the total storage space and available space in Flutter. Tried using [storage_space](https://pub.dev/packages/storage_space) libary but it excludes system reserved space. Eg- If the device storage is 128 GB, total storage returned by the library is 111.9 GB.
Is there any other way to find that?

```
 StorageSpace storageSpace = await getStorageSpace(
            lowOnSpaceThreshold: totalSize!, // 2GB
            fractionDigits: 1,
          );
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Chinmay Nanaware, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [disk_space](https://pub.dev/packages/disk_space/example) package?

Comment: It also has a similar issue.
https://github.com/mboeddeker/disk_space/issues/6

Comment: what about this [System Info](https://pub.dev/packages/system_info)

Comment: It has been flagged as discontinued.